# Response from geocoding API

Tags: google-maps-api-3, flutter, dart, google-geocoding-api

I'm able to get the fully formatted address from the api,

> "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA"

for example.

How do i "breaking to pieces" this formatted address(city, street, country etc)?

code for getting the fully address -

```
   final formattedAddress =decodedResponse['results'][0]['formatted_address']
```

Comment: Use the split() method in this String, using , as parameter to break. It'll transform in a List

Comment: The api already gives you the address broken in pieces. Can't recommend parsing it out of the formatted address. Formating differs from country to country.

Comment: @ZeRj is right, If i'm using non-staic values I prefer not breaking the address using split cause there are a differences between countries. How the api is giving me the the address broken in pieces? I got only the fully address as i showed in the post..It is really impossible to get from the api only the city for example?

Comment: See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#GeocodingResponses
The parts should be available with decodedResponse['results'][0]['address_components']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the result from the api(https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#GeocodingResponses)

I can write `decodedResponse['results'][0]['address_components'][0]['long_name']`

The second [0] indicate the location of the type